# jQuery .autocomplete is sticky

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, widget

```
        $("input#lastname").autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.lastname.php"
        });
```

I am experiencing a problem where when I use tab to change text boxes the drop down menu is stuck in the down position. What could be done to solve this type of a problem? I already have something like this also:

```
    $("input#firstname").autocomplete({
      source: "autocomplete.firstname.php"
    }).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $(".ui-menu-item").hide();
      }
    });
```

Which is not exactly what I am intending but perhaps it could be modified? I am also noticing that on .hide there is still showing at the bottom remnants of the menu on enter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lags because your `source` is a PHP file, which has to load and process what ever is on there.

---

A quick and dirty solution would be an AJAX call on load.

```
$(function() {
    var lastnames;

    $.get("autocomplete.lastname.php", function(data) {
       lastnames = data;
    });


    $("input#lastname").autocomplete({
        source: lastnames
    });
});​
```

Comment: What should I do about it? Do you have a change you could recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but tacking on an AJAX call seemed like overkill to me. So, I added a line to close all the autocompletes on my form when the user focuses into the next input box:

```
$("#form input").on("focus", function(e) {
    $("#form autocomplete_input_1, #form autocomplete_input_2").autocomplete( "close" );
});
```

This has the benefit of not interfering with the autocomplete when you need it, but quickly hiding it for those users who can move quickly through the form.